# Preserving trailing zeros when selecting values from Json String using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a third party api that I need to test and need to ensure that the values returned are the exact values sent in the response. For example if a number is returned as 1.000 it needs to be 1.000 and not 1.

I have tried deserializing the string response to a JObject and selecting values into a JToken, but the value for obj1.n2 below ends up being 1. I almost want to select the raw value at a specific path as a string, regardless of the type.

Is there a way using Json.Net I can select obj1.n2 from a string representation of the example below and preserve the trailing zeros?

For example:

{
"obj1": [{
"n1": "n",
"n2": 1.000,
"n3": true
},
{
"n1": "n",
"n2": 10.000,
"n3": false
}]
}

Comment: I'm curious why you need to distinguish between two numeric values representing the same actual value.   The trailing zeros should be meaningless.  If it's meaningful, then perhaps a numeric type is poorly suited for your use case.

Comment: As I am the consumer of this service I have no control over the types and unfortunately I need to test what I receive is actually what has been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because C# decimal types preserve trailing zeros, you can just instruct Json.Net to parse numbers to decimals instead of floating points.  Do this by setting `FloatParseHandling` to `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` as shown here:

```
var json = @"{ ""obj1"": [{ ""n1"": ""n"", ""n2"": 1.000, ""n3"": true }, { ""n1"": ""n"", ""n2"": 10.000, ""n3"": false }] }";

var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(
    json, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal });
```

`token["obj1"][0]["n2"]` will now show `1.000` instead of `1`.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. I will speak to the developers of said api but unlikely to get any changes due to multiple consumers.